# Find cell with entry from user prompt and set active cell

Tags: excel, vba, search, prompt

I'm looking for a simple macro that will display a user prompt for a value and then search column A for this value and go to that cell

Answer (score 0):

This is to find a string:

```
Sub FindAndGo()
    Dim x As String, r As Range
    With Application
        x = .InputBox(Prompt:="Enter search value", Type:=2)
        Set r = Range("A:A").Cells.Find(what:=x, after:=Range("A1"))
        .Goto r
    End With
End Sub
```

make proper changes to find a number.